# Sky-Watcher Skyhawk 1145P SynScan AZ GOTO

Tags: astronomy, soft-question, telescopes

What is the experience using the [Sky-Watcher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sky-Watcher) Skyhawk 1145P SynScan AZ GOTO telescope and can it be recommended for a new astronomer? Is it any good?

Comment: It depends on what are you going to do with

Comment: Star gazing and looking at planets etc this will be our first telescope

Comment: Goto mount is one of those things that sounds really good on paper, until you get some experience and learn what it really means.  Unless you're completely unable to read a simple map, a goto mount will more likely get in the way, rather than help.  Get a dobsonian instead, it's more bang for the buck.  Install Stellarium on an iPhone or laptop.  Get the "Turn left at Orion" book.

Answer (score 1):

No, I would not recommend this telescope. It has several counts against it:

1. Small aperture: 150 mm aperture is a recommended minimum.
2. Short focal ratio: Good mainly for low power wide field views, not suitable for planets.
3. Most of the money goes into the computer, very little into the optics.

Instead, I recommend a manual telescope with a large enough aperture to give satisfying views of both planets and deep sky objects. For the same money you can get a larger and more solidly mounted Dobsonian like *[Skywatcher Dobsonian Telescopes - Dobsonian Telescopes by OVL](http://www.opticalvision.co.uk/astronomical_telescopes/sky-watcher/dobsonians)*.

Comment: Thanks all,
i really like the idea of a goto mount, i realise that this is not the best scope and optics are below minium recomendations.  So i have found another one that i think might do the trick.

I am limited for physical space to store the telescope so i have found a small scope with a larger Focal length

SKYWATCHER SKYMAX 102 MAKSUTOV-CASSEGRAIN.
Magnifications (with eyepieces supplied): x52 & x130 Highest Practical Power (Potential): x204 Diameter of Primary Mirror: 102mm Telescope Focal Length: 1300mm (f/12.74)

Thanks for all your responces

Answer (score 0):

It is not very suitable for planets. Actually it's best for the [Moon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon) and large diffuse objects like [nebulae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sky-Watcher), [clusters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_cluster) and [galaxies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy). It is suitable for backyard pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much personal experience of the cheaper goto mounts but I would be suspicious of any goto mount under £300 (thats just the mount!  telescope would be extra.)  I would recommend spending more on optics and solid mount rather than motorised systems for that budget.

A brief look finds [this telescope](http://www.bristolcameras.co.uk/product_info.php?products_id=skywatcher-explorer-150p-eq3-2-912-448-) of similar design but better spec, and a fairly trusty mount.

Comment: Thanks all,
i really like the idea of a goto mount, i realise that this is not the best scope and optics are below minium recomendations.  So i have found another one that i think might do the trick.

I am limited for physical space to store the telescope so i have found a small scope with a larger Focal length

SKYWATCHER SKYMAX 102 MAKSUTOV-CASSEGRAIN.
Magnifications (with eyepieces supplied): x52 & x130 Highest Practical Power (Potential): x204 Diameter of Primary Mirror: 102mm Telescope Focal Length: 1300mm (f/12.74)

Thanks for all your responces